# Esperar un segundo cada iteración de un ciclo sin bloquear la interfaz

Tags: c#, hilos, while

Estoy trabajando con el algoritmo de línea recta que es llamado por un el evento de un botón, y realiza bien su trabajo pero no se alcanza a ver cada impresión de la imagen (Mover()) para ver el camino que siguió, probé con Thread.Sleep(1000) pero bloquea la ventana y de igual forma no se alcanza a ver la impresión, mi algoritmo:

```
public void LineaBresenham(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        int[] coordenadas = new int[2];
        int dX = (x2 - x1);
        int dY = (y2 - y1);
        int incXi, incYi, incXr, incYr;
        if (dX >= 0)
        {
            incXi = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            dX = -dX;
            incXi = -1;
        }
        if (dY >= 0)
        {
            incYi = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            dY = -dY;
            incYi = -1;
        }
        if (dX >= dY)
        {
            incYr = 0;
            incXr = incXi;
        }
        else
        {
            incXr = 0;
            incYr = incYi;
            //Intercambio
            int k = dX;
            dX = dY;
            dY = k;
        }
        coordenadas[0] = x1;
        coordenadas[1] = y1;
        int avR = 2 * dY;
        int av = avR - dX;
        int avI = av - dX;
        //Ciclo 
        while (coordenadas[0] != x2 && coordenadas[1] != y2)
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Mover(coordenadas[0], coordenadas[1]); //Impresión
            if (av >= 0 && VerificarMovimiento(coordenadas[0] + incXi, coordenadas[1] + incYi))
            {
                Ambiente[coordenadas[0], coordenadas[1]].Image = null;
                coordenadas[0] = coordenadas[0] + incXi;
                coordenadas[1] = coordenadas[1] + incYi;
                av = av + avI;
            }
            else if (VerificarMovimiento(coordenadas[0] + incXr, coordenadas[1] + incYr))
            {
                Ambiente[coordenadas[0], coordenadas[1]].Image = null;
                coordenadas[0] = coordenadas[0] + incXr;
                coordenadas[1] = coordenadas[1] + incYr;
                av = av + avR;
            }
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ya no se puede avanzar");
                return;
            }
        }
        EnCasa = true;
    }
```

Básicamente lo que realiza mover es en una matriz de PictureBox establecer la propiedad PictureBox.Image si el PictureBox al que se establecer tiene la propiedad null (no tiene un obstáculo), await tampoco me funcionó y no he encontrado una implementación que me sirva, de ante mano muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Para hacer esto lo más sencillo es crear un hilo y realizar ese proceso con el hilo (imprimir y dormir), así no bloquearás el hilo principal y el proceso se irá realizando en el hilo secundario

Comment: Busca Backgroundworker, esta clase te permite hacer lo que dices sin bloquear la interfaz principal, ademas es muy facil de trabajar con ella

Comment: Utilizas winforms o wpf?

Comment: El problema que tendrás es que si usas hilos no bloqueará la IU pero no puedes actualizar ningún control desde otro hilo que no sea el de la UI. Yo lo haría con las Reactive Extensions.

Comment: He tratado de implementar de distintas formas los hilos y ninguna me ha resultado, el Backgroundworker no me dejaba ver la impresión del movimiento, y utilizo Windows Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que encontré fue crear otro método para separar un poco de los cambios visuales y hacerlo asíncrono con un retraso de tiempo y después seguir con el otro cambio visual, de la misma manera el hice asíncrono al método que llamaba varias veces al nuevo método y continuo con el flujo normal hasta que termine todo el ciclo.

```
private async void BotonLineaRecta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Link.LineaBresenhamAsync();
    if (Link.EnCasa)
    {
        BloquearEscenario();
    }
}

public async Task LineaBresenhamAsync() 
{
    int dX = (Ventana.Casa.X - X);
    int dY = (Ventana.Casa.Y - Y);
    int incXi, incYi, incXr, incYr;
    if (dX >= 0)
    {
        incXi = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        dX = -dX;
        incXi = -1;
    }
    if (dY >= 0)
    {
        incYi = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        dY = -dY;
        incYi = -1;
    }
    if (dX >= dY)
    {
        incYr = 0;
        incXr = incXi;
    }
    else
    {
        incXr = 0;
        incYr = incYi;
        int k = dX;
        dX = dY;
        dY = k;
    }
    int avR = 2 * dY;
    int av = avR - dX;
    int avI = av - dX;
    while (X != Ventana.Casa.X && Y != Ventana.Casa.Y)
    {
        Colocar();
        if (av >= 0 && VerificarMovimiento(X + incXi, Y + incYi))
        {
            await Task.Run(QuitarAsync);
            X = X + incXi;
            Y = Y + incYi;
            av = av + avI;
        }
        else if (VerificarMovimiento(X + incXr, Y + incYr))
        {
            await Task.Run(QuitarAsync);
            Task.WaitAll();
            X = X + incXr;
            Y = Y + incYr;
            av = av + avR;
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ya no se puede avanzar");
            return;
        }
    }
    EnCasa = true;
}

public async Task QuitarAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Ventana.Ambiente[X, Y].Image = null;
}
```

Comment: Podes aclarar en que se diferencia esta respuesta de la respuesta aceptada? si esta es la respuesta correcta, deberia ser la aceptada. Si no, crea confusion sobre como se debe hacer.

Comment: Lo siento, ya marque esta como aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución rápida y nada elegante puede ser mandar llamar el método DoEvents para que se dibuje todo antes del Thread sleep, la UI se seguira congelando pero por lo menos se vera lo que se dibuja.

```
Application.DoEvents();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Lo mas recomendable es hacer un nuevo hilo.

Comment: Ya lo había hecho así pero como dices se congela el UI y es precisamente lo que trato de evitar.

Answer (score 0):

Declara una clase que contenga dos coordenadas:

```
public class Coord
{
    public int Coord1 { get; set;}
    public int Coord2 { get; set;}
}
```

Modifica tu método Mover para que acepte un objeto de tipo Coord en vez de dos enteros, el objeto de tipo Coord ya lleva esos dos datos.

Modifica tu metodo de Linea para que sea asíncrono y acepte un parámetro adicional:

```
public async Task LineaBresenham(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, IProgress<Coord> progress)
{

    int[] coordenadas = new int[2];
    int dX = (x2 - x1);
    int dY = (y2 - y1);
    int incXi, incYi, incXr, incYr;
    if (dX >= 0)
    {
        incXi = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        dX = -dX;
        incXi = -1;
    }
    if (dY >= 0)
    {
        incYi = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        dY = -dY;
        incYi = -1;
    }
    if (dX >= dY)
    {
        incYr = 0;
        incXr = incXi;
    }
    else
    {
        incXr = 0;
        incYr = incYi;
        //Intercambio
        int k = dX;
        dX = dY;
        dY = k;
    }
    coordenadas[0] = x1;
    coordenadas[1] = y1;
    int avR = 2 * dY;
    int av = avR - dX;
    int avI = av - dX;
    //Ciclo 
    while (coordenadas[0] != x2 && coordenadas[1] != y2)
    { 
        // No uses Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // si quieres hacer un sleep usa:
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        // no llames aquí a Mover(coordenadas[0], coordenadas[1]); debes hacer esto:
        if (progress != null)
            progress.Report(new Coord { Coord1 = coordenadas[0], Coord2 = coordenadas[1] });
        if (av >= 0 && VerificarMovimiento(coordenadas[0] + incXi, coordenadas[1] + incYi))
        {
            Ambiente[coordenadas[0], coordenadas[1]].Image = null;
            coordenadas[0] = coordenadas[0] + incXi;
            coordenadas[1] = coordenadas[1] + incYi;
            av = av + avI;
        }
        else if (VerificarMovimiento(coordenadas[0] + incXr, coordenadas[1] + incYr))
        {
            Ambiente[coordenadas[0], coordenadas[1]].Image = null;
            coordenadas[0] = coordenadas[0] + incXr;
            coordenadas[1] = coordenadas[1] + incYr;
            av = av + avR;
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ya no se puede avanzar");
            return;
        }
    }
    EnCasa = true;
}
```

En tu método del evento click (márcalo como asincrono):

```
private async void BotonLineaRecta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var progress = new Progress<Coord>(Mover); // Mover es el método que llamabas desde LineaBresenham
    await Adrian.LineaBresenham(XAvatar, YAvatar, XCasa, YCasa, progress);
    if (Adrian.EnCasa)
    {
        BloquearEscenario();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Hay otra opción, veo que utilizas una clase donde tienes varios métodos, como por ejemplo el método Mover, que son los que te dan problemas en la interfaz, lo que puedes hacer es que en la clase donde tienes esos métodos le puedas pasar en el constructor el SynchronizationContext actual.

Por ejemplo, en tu clase "Link" agregas un campo privado:

```
SynchronizationContext context;
```

En el constructor aceptas ese dato:

```
public Link(string rutaImagen, SynchronizationContext context)
{
    RutaImagen = rutaImagen;
    this.context = context;
    EnCasa = false;
}
```

Cuando inicialices un objeto de tipo Link lo haces así:

```
var Adrian = new Link(rutaImagenAvatar, SynchronizationContext.Current);
```

Y en cualquier método de la clase Link que ejecute en otro hilo, cuando quieras hacer cambios a la IU lo haces así:

```
context.Post(state => textbox1.Text = state as string, "Hola");
```

Donde textbox1 puede ser cualquier control que quieras modificar.

O si quieres puedes hacer un método que es donde actualiza la IU:

```
private void UpdateTextBox(object state)
{
    textbox.Text = state as string;
}
```

Y lo utilizas así:

```
context.Post(UpdateTextBox, "Hola");
```

De esta manera puedes actualizar la IU desde otro hilo.

Comment: Lo acabo de tratar de implementar sin éxito, me quedan dos dudas, donde devuelvo mis valores a coordenadas[] y en el evento del botón (aquí marca el error) veo el pase de parámetros de dos 0 cuando yo paso x1, x2, y1, y2, no entiendo como utilizaría estos valores si no los paso, tal vez con la información que proporcioné aquí no basta, por ejemplo LineaBresenham y Mover son métodos de otra clase llamados desde el form principal, te dejo el enlace: https://github.com/adrianarroyoceja/AmbienteZelda muchas gracias.

Comment: Le he hechado un ojo a tu código, vas a tener que separar la lógica del método Mover, para que no haga cambios a la UI y solo regrese tus coordenadas[], y pasar la lógica que modifica la interfaz a otro método. Hay otra opción, deja edito la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo corregí, te doy por buena tu respuesta porque me basé en la primera, al final tuve que hacer unos cambios pero con el ejemplo de await lo logré, gracias!